# CSS / JS : Animate a vertical line on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, line

I'm trying to animate a line on scroll like this website (h3:before) :
https://www.fhoke.com/

```css
.line {
  display : table;
  transition: opacity ease 0.4s;
}

.line:before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 0.10rem;
  height: 114px;
  top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  transition: height ease 0.4s 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc auctor lectus nec imperdiet volutpat. Curabitur in pharetra purus. Nunc a tortor eros.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc auctor lectus nec imperdiet volutpat. Curabitur in pharetra purus. Nunc a tortor eros.</p>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: you need some js and bind event to scroll

Comment: I’ve tried with JS but the line appears at the first scroll and not when I arrived on it with the screen

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( window ).scroll(function() {
   var currentpos = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (currentpos == 0) {
               $(".line").removeClass("scrolled");
            } else {
               $(".line").addClass("scrolled");
            }
   
});
```

```css
.line {
  display : table;
  transition: opacity ease 0.4s;
}

.line:before {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 0.10rem;
  height: 114px;
  top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  transition: height ease 0.4s 0.1s;
}
.line.scrolled:before{
height:180px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="line">

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc auctor lectus nec imperdiet volutpat. Curabitur in pharetra purus. Nunc a tortor eros.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc auctor lectus nec imperdiet volutpat. Curabitur in pharetra purus. Nunc a tortor eros.</p>

</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc auctor lectus nec imperdiet volutpat. Curabitur in pharetra purus. Nunc a tortor eros.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc auctor lectus nec imperdiet volutpat. Curabitur in pharetra purus. Nunc a tortor eros.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc auctor lectus nec imperdiet volutpat. Curabitur in pharetra purus. Nunc a tortor eros.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc auctor lectus nec imperdiet volutpat. Curabitur in pharetra purus. Nunc a tortor eros.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc auctor lectus nec imperdiet volutpat. Curabitur in pharetra purus. Nunc a tortor eros.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc auctor lectus nec imperdiet volutpat. Curabitur in pharetra purus. Nunc a tortor eros.</p>
```

Comment: Can someone help me ?